# Select bones and weigth painting won't let me do anthying

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to select a bone for weighing painting but it's selecting all blue bones, it won't let me do anything. How do I get select one bone instead of all bones?    [image]

[image]

I have this [image]

Comment: First thing, you need to parent the object to the armature. Once done, select the armature in Object mode, shift select the object, switch to Weight Paint mode, then press Ctrl left click to select the bone, does it work? vIf not please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AXVLk6bX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AXVLk6bX/)

Comment: It seems to work, Ctrl left click lets me select the bone I want, Shift left click if you want to select several bones, I had to disable the Paint Mask option (top lef of the 3D view) but it seems like it was disabled when you took the screenshots: https://zupimages.net/up/23/18/udrk.gif